# Rodrigues Rotation about an arbitrary axis

Tags: c#, matrix, rotational-matrices

Suppose, I have a candidate vector `v(vx, vy, vz)`. I want to rotate it `theta` degrees about an arbitrary axis that starts at vector `s(sx,sy,sz)` and ends at vector `e(ex, ey, ez)` when the origin of the axes is located at `o(ox, oy, oz)`.

So, I am doing the **Rodrigues rotation** in the following source code, but it is not giving the correct results:

```
public class RotoTranslation
{
    private readonly Vec3 origin;
    private readonly double cosTheta;
    private readonly double sinTheta;
    private readonly Vec3 axis;
    private readonly Matrix3x3 rotationMatrix;
    private readonly Matrix3x3 translationMatrix;
    private readonly Matrix3x3 invTranslationMatrix;
    public RotoTranslation(
                Vec3 origin, 
                Vec3 start, 
                Vec3 end, 
                double angle_rad)
    {
        this.origin = origin;
        this.axis = Vec3.Normalize(end - start);
        this.cosTheta = Math.Cos(angle_rad);
        this.sinTheta = Math.Sin(angle_rad);

        Matrix3x3 uOuter = 
            Vec3.OuterProduct_mat(axis, axis);
        Matrix3x3 uCross = 
            new Matrix3x3(0.0f, -axis.z, axis.y,                   
                        axis.z, 0.0f, -axis.x,                
                        -axis.y, axis.x, 0.0f);

        rotationMatrix = 
             cosTheta * Matrix3x3.Identity()
             + (1.0f - cosTheta) * uOuter
             + sinTheta * uCross;

        translationMatrix = 
             Matrix3x3.CreateTranslation(-origin);
        rotationMatrix = 
             rotationMatrix * translationMatrix;
        invTranslationMatrix = 
            Matrix3x3.CreateTranslation(origin);
    }
    public Vec3 RotateVector(Vec3 vector)
    {
        Vec3 transformedVector = 
            Vec3.TransformNormal(
                vector - origin, 
                rotationMatrix);
        return Vec3.Transform(
                transformedVector, 
                invTranslationMatrix);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Vec3 origin = new Vec3(1, 1, 1);
    Vec3 start = new Vec3(1, 1, 1);
    Vec3 end = new Vec3(4, 4, 4);
    Vec3 candidate = new Vec3(3,3,3);

    double degrees = 360;
    degrees = degrees * (Math.PI / 180.0);

    RotoTranslation rot = 
        new RotoTranslation(origin, 
                            start, 
                            end, 
                            degrees);

    Vec3 rotated = rot.RotateVector(candidate);

    Assert.AreEqual(candidate[0], rotated[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual(candidate[1], rotated[1]);
    Assert.AreEqual(candidate[2], rotated[2]);
}
```

If I rotate a vector around an axis 360 degrees, it should be at the same position as the initial vector. However, that is not the case here.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

**N.B.** I must use `Matrix3x3`, rather than a `Matrix4x4` (augmented matrix).

---

**Full Source code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

public class Vec3
{
    public double x, y, z;

    public Vec3(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public static double DistanceSquared(Vec3 t1, Vec3 t2)
    {
        double x = t1.x - t2.x;
        double y = t1.y - t2.y;
        double z = t1.z - t2.z;
        return x * x + y * y + z * z;
    }

    public static double Distance(Vec3 t1, Vec3 t2)
    {
        if (t1 == null) throw new Exception("point1 is null");
        if (t2 == null) throw new Exception("point2 is null");

        return Math.Sqrt(DistanceSquared(t1, t2));
    }

    public Vec3 Subtract(Vec3 rhs)
    {
        return new Vec3(this.x - rhs.x, this.y - rhs.y, this.z - rhs.z);
    }

    public static Vec3 operator -(Vec3 a, Vec3 b)
    {
        return new Vec3(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y, a.z - b.z);
    }


    public Vec3 Scale(double rhs)
    {
        return new Vec3(this.x * rhs, this.y * rhs, this.z * rhs);
    }

    public double MagnitudeSquared()
    {
        return this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y + this.z * this.z;
    }

    public static double Dot(Vec3 a, Vec3 b)
    {
        return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z;
    }


    public Vec3 Cross(Vec3 other)
    {
        double a = this.y * other.z - this.z * other.y;
        double b = this.z * other.x - this.x * other.z;
        double c = this.x * other.y - this.y * other.x;
        return new Vec3(a, b, c);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{x,8:0.000}{y,8:0.000}{z,8:0.000}";
    }

    public Vec3(string x, string y, string z)
    {
        this.x = Convert.ToDouble(x);
        this.y = Convert.ToDouble(y);
        this.z = Convert.ToDouble(z);
    }

    public Vec3(string xyz)
    {
        string[] vals = xyz.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        this.x = Convert.ToDouble(vals[0].Trim());
        this.y = Convert.ToDouble(vals[1].Trim());
        this.z = Convert.ToDouble(vals[2].Trim());
    }

    public Vec3()
    {
    }

    public static Vec3 Normalize(Vec3 vec)
    {
        double mag = Math.Sqrt(vec.x * vec.x + vec.y * vec.y + vec.z * vec.z);
        return new Vec3(vec.x / mag, vec.y / mag, vec.z / mag);
    }

    public static Vec3 OuterProduct(Vec3 a, Vec3 b)
    {
        double x = a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y;
        double y = a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z;
        double z = a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x;
        return new Vec3(x, y, z);
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 OuterProduct_mat(Vec3 lhs, Vec3 rhs)
    {
        double[,] data = new double[3, 3];

        data[0, 0] = lhs.x * rhs.x;
        data[0, 1] = lhs.x * rhs.y;
        data[0, 2] = lhs.x * rhs.z;

        data[1, 0] = lhs.y * rhs.x;
        data[1, 1] = lhs.y * rhs.y;
        data[1, 2] = lhs.y * rhs.z;

        data[2, 0] = lhs.z * rhs.x;
        data[2, 1] = lhs.z * rhs.y;
        data[2, 2] = lhs.z * rhs.z;

        return new Matrix3x3(data[0, 0], data[0, 1], data[0, 2],
                             data[1, 0], data[1, 1], data[1, 2],
                             data[2, 0], data[2, 1], data[2, 2]);
    }

    public static Vec3 operator -(Vec3 v)
    {
        return new Vec3(-v.x, -v.y, -v.z);
    }

    public static Vec3 Transform(Vec3 v, Matrix3x3 m)
    {
        double x = m[0] * v.x + m[1] * v.y + m[2] * v.z;
        double y = m[3] * v.x + m[4] * v.y + m[5] * v.z;
        double z = m[6] * v.x + m[7] * v.y + m[8] * v.z;
        return new Vec3(x, y, z);
    }

    public static Vec3 TransformNormal(Vec3 normal, Matrix3x3 matrix)
    {
        return new Vec3(
            matrix[0] * normal.x + matrix[3] * normal.y + matrix[6] * normal.z,
            matrix[1] * normal.x + matrix[4] * normal.y + matrix[7] * normal.z,
            matrix[2] * normal.x + matrix[5] * normal.y + matrix[8] * normal.z
        );
    }

    public static Vec3 operator +(Vec3 v1, Vec3 v2)
    {
        return new Vec3(v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y, v1.z + v2.z);
    }

    public double this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    return x;
                case 1:
                    return y;
                case 2:
                    return z;
                default:
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
        set
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    x = value;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    y = value;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    z = value;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Matrix3x3
{
    const int rows = 3;
    const int cols = 3;
    private List<double> data2d;

    public Matrix3x3()
    {
        data2d = new List<double>(new double[rows * cols]);
    }

    public Matrix3x3(double x1, double y1, double z1,
                     double x2, double y2, double z2,
                     double x3, double y3, double z3)
    {
        data2d = new List<double>(new double[rows * cols]);
        data2d[0] = x1; data2d[1] = y1; data2d[2] = z1;
        data2d[3] = x2; data2d[4] = y2; data2d[5] = z2;
        data2d[6] = x3; data2d[7] = y3; data2d[8] = z3;
    }

    public double this[int i]
    {
        get { return data2d[i]; }
        set { data2d[i] = value; }
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 Add(Matrix3x3 lhs, Matrix3x3 rhs)
    {
        Matrix3x3 result = new Matrix3x3();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
        {
            result[i] = lhs[i] + rhs[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 Sub(Matrix3x3 lhs, Matrix3x3 rhs)
    {
        Matrix3x3 result = new Matrix3x3();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
        {
            result[i] = lhs[i] - rhs[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 mul_scalar(Matrix3x3 lhs, double rhs)
    {
        Matrix3x3 result = new Matrix3x3();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
        {
            result[i] = lhs[i] * rhs;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 div_scalar(Matrix3x3 lhs, double rhs)
    {
        Matrix3x3 result = new Matrix3x3();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
        {
            result[i] = lhs[i] / rhs;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static Vec3 mul_vec_mut(Matrix3x3 lhs, Vec3 rhs)
    {
        double x = lhs[0] * rhs.x + lhs[1] * rhs.y + lhs[2] * rhs.z;
        double y = lhs[3] * rhs.x + lhs[4] * rhs.y + lhs[5] * rhs.z;
        double z = lhs[6] * rhs.x + lhs[7] * rhs.y + lhs[8] * rhs.z;
        return new Vec3(x, y, z);
    }

    public double det()
    {
        Matrix3x3 lhs = this;
        double a = lhs[0] * (lhs[4] * lhs[8] - lhs[5] * lhs[7]);
        double b = lhs[1] * (lhs[3] * lhs[8] - lhs[5] * lhs[6]);
        double c = lhs[2] * (lhs[3] * lhs[7] - lhs[4] * lhs[6]);
        double returns = a - b + c;
        return returns;
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 mul_mat_mut(Matrix3x3 lhs, Matrix3x3 rhs)
    {
        Matrix3x3 result = new Matrix3x3(
            lhs[0] * rhs[0] + lhs[1] * rhs[3] + lhs[2] * rhs[6], // row 1, column 1
            lhs[0] * rhs[1] + lhs[1] * rhs[4] + lhs[2] * rhs[7], // row 1, column 2
            lhs[0] * rhs[2] + lhs[1] * rhs[5] + lhs[2] * rhs[8], // row 1, column 3
            lhs[3] * rhs[0] + lhs[4] * rhs[3] + lhs[5] * rhs[6], // row 2, column 1
            lhs[3] * rhs[1] + lhs[4] * rhs[4] + lhs[5] * rhs[7], // row 2, column 2
            lhs[3] * rhs[2] + lhs[4] * rhs[5] + lhs[5] * rhs[8], // row 2, column 3
            lhs[6] * rhs[0] + lhs[7] * rhs[3] + lhs[8] * rhs[6], // row 3, column 1
            lhs[6] * rhs[1] + lhs[7] * rhs[4] + lhs[8] * rhs[7], // row 3, column 2
            lhs[6] * rhs[2] + lhs[7] * rhs[5] + lhs[8] * rhs[8]); // row 3, column 3

        return result;
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 inverse(Matrix3x3 lhs)
    {
        Matrix3x3 temp = null;
        double _det = lhs.det();
        if (_det != 0.0)
        {
            double inv_det = 1.0 / _det;
            temp = new Matrix3x3(
                lhs[4] * lhs[8] - lhs[5] * lhs[7],
                lhs[2] * lhs[7] - lhs[1] * lhs[8],
                lhs[1] * lhs[5] - lhs[2] * lhs[4],
                lhs[5] * lhs[6] - lhs[3] * lhs[8],
                lhs[0] * lhs[8] - lhs[2] * lhs[6],
                lhs[2] * lhs[3] - lhs[0] * lhs[5],
                lhs[3] * lhs[7] - lhs[4] * lhs[6],
                lhs[1] * lhs[6] - lhs[0] * lhs[7],
                lhs[0] * lhs[4] - lhs[1] * lhs[3]);
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 Identity()
    {
        return new Matrix3x3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                                        0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 OuterProduct(Matrix3x3 a, Matrix3x3 b)
    {
        Matrix3x3 result = new Matrix3x3();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                result[i * cols + j] = a[i] * b[j];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 operator *(Matrix3x3 lhs, double rhs)
    {
        Matrix3x3 result = new Matrix3x3();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
        {
            result[i] = lhs[i] * rhs;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 operator *(double lhs, Matrix3x3 rhs)
    {
        return rhs * lhs;
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 operator +(Matrix3x3 lhs, Matrix3x3 rhs)
    {
        Matrix3x3 result = new Matrix3x3();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
        {
            result[i] = lhs[i] + rhs[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 CreateTranslation(Vec3 translation)
    {
        return new Matrix3x3(
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            translation.x, translation.y, translation.z
        );
    }

    public static Matrix3x3 operator *(Matrix3x3 lhs, Matrix3x3 rhs)
    {
        Matrix3x3 result = new Matrix3x3();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                double sum = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++)
                {
                    sum += lhs[i * cols + k] * rhs[k * cols + j];
                }
                result[i * cols + j] = sum;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class RotoTranslation
{
    private readonly Vec3 origin;
    private readonly double cosTheta;
    private readonly double sinTheta;
    private readonly Vec3 axis;
    private readonly Matrix3x3 rotationMatrix;
    private readonly Matrix3x3 translationMatrix;
    private readonly Matrix3x3 invTranslationMatrix;

    public RotoTranslation(Vec3 origin, Vec3 start, Vec3 end, double angle_rad)
    {
        this.origin = origin;
        this.axis = Vec3.Normalize(end - start);
        this.cosTheta = Math.Cos(angle_rad);
        this.sinTheta = Math.Sin(angle_rad);

        Matrix3x3 uOuter = Vec3.OuterProduct_mat(axis, axis);
        Matrix3x3 uCross = new Matrix3x3(
                                           0.0f, -axis.z, axis.y,
                                           axis.z, 0.0f, -axis.x,
                                          -axis.y, axis.x, 0.0f
                                        );

        rotationMatrix = cosTheta * Matrix3x3.Identity()
                                 + (1.0f - cosTheta) * uOuter
                                 + sinTheta * uCross;

        translationMatrix = Matrix3x3.CreateTranslation(-origin);
        rotationMatrix = rotationMatrix * translationMatrix;
        invTranslationMatrix = Matrix3x3.CreateTranslation(origin);
    }

    public Vec3 RotateVector(Vec3 vector)
    {
        Vec3 transformedVector = Vec3.TransformNormal(vector - origin, rotationMatrix);
        return Vec3.Transform(transformedVector, invTranslationMatrix);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class RotoTranslationUnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Vec3 origin = new Vec3(1, 1, 1);
        Vec3 start = new Vec3(1, 1, 1);
        Vec3 end = new Vec3(4, 4, 4);
        Vec3 candidate = new Vec3(3,3,3);

        double degrees = 360;
        degrees = degrees * (Math.PI / 180.0);

        RotoTranslation rot = new RotoTranslation(origin, start, end, degrees);

        Vec3 rotated = rot.RotateVector(candidate);

        Assert.AreEqual(candidate[0], rotated[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual(candidate[1], rotated[1]);
        Assert.AreEqual(candidate[2], rotated[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: your progrm is to complex to read..and understant .the best is to give one or two samples with the initial vectors , angle et result waited...

Comment: You are doing the Rodrigues rotation matrix?

Comment: Note that `Math.Sin(Math.PI)` does **not** equal zero. How close are the values? Is it a matter of precision, or something wrong in the procedure?

Comment: vector <3, 3, 3>  angle  <0, 1, 0> must give <3, 3, 3>?

Comment: I am concerned because in 3D you need a 4×4 matrix to combine rotation and translation. The translation `Matrix3x3` does not make sense to me. Also show your matrix multiplication operator overload is it might follow a different convention.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4680608/is-it-possible-to-do-rotation-translation-using-3-element-vectors-and-3-times3

Comment: @user366312 - as you can see translation is done as a vector addition and not with a 3×3 matrix. Your code needs to follow this example. Take the point and subtract the pivot, rotate the vector and then add the pivot.

Comment: I mean really, what does `Matrix3x3.CreateTranslation()` look like? Please share more details because I am convinced this is where the problem lies.

Comment: @user366312 - dont put code in comments, and don't link to external URL much might not be available in the future. Please [edit] your question with all relevant information (and keep the link for testing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this method

```
public static Matrix3x3 CreateTranslation(Vec3 translation)
{
    return new Matrix3x3(
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        translation.x, translation.y, translation.z
    );
}
```

[To represent an offset in 3D with a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)#Matrix_representation) you need a 4×4 matrix arranged as follows

```
                    | 1    0    0    x |
translate3(x,y,z) = | 0    1    0    y |
                    | 0    0    1    z |
                    | 0    0    0    1 |
```

Instead of handling the translation with a matrix operation, just change the code to use linear algebra

```
public RotoTranslation(Vec3 origin, Vec3 start, Vec3 end, double angle_rad)
{
    this.origin = origin;
    this.axis = Vec3.Normalize(end - start);
    this.cosTheta = Math.Cos(angle_rad);
    this.sinTheta = Math.Sin(angle_rad);

    Matrix3x3 uOuter = Vec3.OuterProduct_mat(axis, axis);
    Matrix3x3 uCross = new Matrix3x3(
                                       0.0f, -axis.z, axis.y,
                                       axis.z, 0.0f, -axis.x,
                                      -axis.y, axis.x, 0.0f
                                    );

    rotationMatrix = cosTheta * Matrix3x3.Identity()
                             + (1.0f - cosTheta) * uOuter
                             + sinTheta * uCross;

}

public Vec3 RotateVector(Vec3 vector)
{
    Vec3 transformedVector = vector - origin;
    transformedVector = Vec3.Transform(transformedVector, rotationMatrix );
    return transformedVector + origin;
}
```

`translationMatrix` and `InvTranslationMatrix` are not needed. You have the `origin` vector stored and that all you need.

Comment: `rotationMatrix = cosTheta * Matrix3x3.Identity() + (1.0f - cosTheta) * uOuter + sinTheta * uCross;` --- Is this formula correct? Where are ***u*** and ***v*** here?

Comment: Suppose we have a vector ***v*** that we want to rotate about an axis represented by a unit vector ***u***. The Rodrigues formula gives the rotated vector ***v'*** as:

***v' = v cos(theta) + (u x v) sin(theta) + u(u . v)(1 - cos(theta))***

where ***theta*** is the angle of rotation in radians, and ***x*** represents the cross product of two vectors.

Comment: @user366312 - I assumed your Rodrigues formula is correct and just copied your code here, To answer your question look at the new `RotateVector()`.

Comment: @user366312 - Your formula for rotation is correct. Here are the [two forms](https://i.imgur.com/icnfy7f.png) of the rotation matrix about an arbitrary axis **u**.